# Doing math on a for loop variable in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two for loops that I'm going through:
The first is creating an array called valuesDeletion that puts the row number in position [i] unless a condition is met, in which case it puts 'y'.
The second one is checking valuesDeletion for any 'y' and deleting that row.
The problem is, the rows I should be deleting are actually j+1 due to the way ranges are set up and stuff, but I can't seem to do math on the variable j.

I've tried:

- parseInt(j)+1
- +j + 1
- +j + +1
- parseFloat(j) + 1
- etc...

Everything I do just concats the two together giving me things like 11 instead of 2 and 111 instead of 12. It seems like I have something fundamentally wrong with my logic I guess. I'm new to javascript as a whole- so if more context is needed (aka the rest of my code) just let me know and I'll be happy to provide.

```
myFunction() {
      for ( var j = 10; j >= 0; j-- ) {
          Logger.log('j: '+ j + 1);
        }
}
```

Desired result is:
11
10
9
etc...

Comment: The code isn't complete. Please checkout [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén I've updated the code snippet to be minimal but reproducible.

Comment: The site guidelines also require the code to be complete :)

Comment: "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included"
I believe that's all you need to run it through a console or website of some kind and read the log. The problem itself is quite simple (and already solved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'j: '+ j` is a string.  When you add `1` to that string, you end up doing string concatenation.

You need to use parentheses to perform the addition first:

`'j: '+ (j + 1)`

Comment: So simple. Thank you so much. That's the problem with not having a formal education in this stuff, but stackoverflow is a better teacher imo.